# Python dataframe linear interpolation by row

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

i have a tyre teperaure sensor the reads 5 points accorss the inside of the tire carcass.
I have this temperatures as 5 columns in a pandas dataframe and i have the spatial cohordinates of each point in other 5 columns.
I would like to calcolate the linear interpolation slope of the 5 points for each row, but since is a lot of data i don't want to do it iterating trough each row....

my dataframe looks like this (it's fake data just to explain):

```
   FL_IR_Temp_Ch1  FL_IR_Temp_Ch2  FL_IR_Temp_Ch3  FL_IR_Temp_Ch4  ...  1  2  3  4
0            29.0           27.75            27.5           26.25  ...  1  2  3  4
1            29.2           28.45            29.5           28.54  ...  1  2  3  4
2            29.5           28.15            27.6           27.25  ...  1  2  3  4
3            29.7           28.15            24.5           24.25  ...  1  2  3  4
4            29.8           28.85            25.5           28.25  ...  1  2  3  4
```

I need to add an extra columns that will contain the slope of the linear interpolation for each row.
I tested with sklearn and di something like:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
y = [df['FL_IR_Temp_Ch1'],df['FL_IR_Temp_Ch2'],df['FL_IR_Temp_Ch3'],df['FL_IR_Temp_Ch4'],df['FL_IR_Temp_Ch5']]

x = [df['0'],df['1'],df['2'],df['3'],df['4']]
reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
```

but if i try to fit for example a new column with df['1'] as starting data i was expecting to have a new column with all the slope coefficents but instead i have a an error.

```
df['m']=reg.predict(df['1'])

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1].

Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

What i'm missing is why my linear regession ask for a bidimensional imput array as i train with X and Y therfore if i give it a new X i should receive a new Y.

Comment: Your `x` matrix has a number of columns. However, when you try to do your prediction you only pass one column, but the model you have made is expecting 5.

Comment: I just need to transpose x vector ?